# change the word cloud when the onchange functions is triggered

Tags: javascript, d3.js, append, html-select

I want to change the word cloud when the onchange functions is triggered.
in my current scriupt bellow, when I change the selection from the drop down list the other image shows up on my chrome windows, I think this might have something to do with this like `d3.select("body").append("svg")`

How can I show one wordcloud at a time and not append to the current windows?
I tried `d3.select("body") = "svg"` instead but didn't work, I tried to remove empty `clear` the screen `body` element and then shows up the word cloud didn't work too.

Any hint will be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="js/d3.js"></script>
<script src="js/d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>
<script>

function displayResult()
{
  //location.reload();
  //var e = document.getElementsByTagName('svg');
  //e.removeChild(document.body.svg);

  var client_name=document.getElementById("client_name");  
  var client_nameSelected = client_name.options[client_name.selectedIndex].value;

  //alert(client_nameSelected);

  var fill = d3.scale.category20();
  //var ClientName = {"Hello":0.10 , "world":0.20, "normally cool!":0.25, "you":0.15, "want":0.60, "more":0.45, "words":0.90 };
  var data = { 'name1':{"Hello":0.10 , "world":0.20, "normally cool!":0.65, "you":0.15, "want":0.60, "more":0.85, "words":0.90 }, 'name2':{"Hello":0.10 , "world":0.20, "normally cool!":0.25, "you you":0.15, "Hug":0.99, "more feedback":0.45, "words":0.90 }};

  var ClientName = data[client_nameSelected];
  var keysdic = Object.keys(ClientName);
  //document.write(keysdic);

  d3.layout.cloud().size([600, 600])
      .words( [].concat(keysdic)
        .map(function(d) {
        var wordsize = 10 + ClientName[d] * 40 ;      
        result =  {text: d, size: wordsize };
        return result;
      }))

      .padding(5)
      .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
      .font("Impact")
      .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
      .on("end", draw)
      .start();


  function draw(words) {
    d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("padding", 60)
        .attr("width", 600)
        .attr("height", 600)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(150,150)")
      .selectAll("text")
        .data(words)
      .enter().append("text")
        .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
        .style("font-family", "Impact")
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
        })
        .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
  }

}
</script>

<body>

Client Name List  :
<select name = 'client_name' id = "client_name" onchange="displayResult();" >
  <option value='name1'>name1</option>
  <option value='name2'>name2</option>
</select><br />

<body>
```

Comment: I would suggest that you have a look at one of the many D3 tutorials before you jump in at the deep end.

Comment: Your draw() function is a one liner. But your data set is nested. Try this http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218 which shows the life cycle of d3 elements.